Can I get run details of a databricks job that provides similar data without using api '/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get'
I am new to databricks world. So please bear with me. I have a notebook, which is attached to a task at the end of a job. This task will pull the status of all other tasks and check if they are success or failure. Depending on that, this last task will send a slack notification (custom one) to the channel. Below is my code.
def get_job_run_details(run_id):
    url = job_run_url
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_token}"
    }
    params = {
        "run_id": run_id
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    return response.json()

# Get job run details
run_details = get_job_run_details(run_id)
tasks = run_details.get('tasks', [])
# Check the status of all tasks
job_status = "completed successfully"
for task in tasks:
    if 'state' in task and 'result_state' in task['state']:
        if task['state']['result_state'] != "SUCCESS":
            job_status = "failed"
            break

Now the problem is the bearer token. I am using a personal auth token. the documentation to generate a token using client_id/secret isn't very clear. I cannot use personal token in production. I need to generate the bearer token using oauth. I was thinking is there another way to fetch the run details without even using the API. the Service principal should have access to the meta data of the current job and there should be some way to access that metadata without having to go through the API route.
